# How to build a website with multi level data processing

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I want to build a site whose work is to take data from a site put it into another site and get result and then result into another site and then show that result on my site is it possible to do so ?

Comment: It is possible by opening and controlling a browser programmatically (if the websites you want to use do not offer a real API). This is easiest (IMHO) in JavaScript with [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [playwright](https://playwright.dev) but you can use most languages with [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev)

Comment: You use APIs to do this properly, not website scraping.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can capture website data with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) webdriver and extract html with [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
After extracting the information, you can create routines that send the data to other sites.